# Rails search string works under Sqlite3 but not under postgres in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, production

I have a search string that is designed to look for a keyword (search term) in 3 fields, and then compare to a geographic area.  It works in Sqlite3, but the only portion that works in Postgres (production) is the geographic search.  I know it must be something about the search string not conforming to Postgres, but I cannot find the issue.

```
def self.search(params)
  listings = Listing.all
  listings = listings.where("title LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? OR shortdescription LIKE ?", "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search]}%") if params[:search].present?
  listings = listings.near(params[:location], 75) if params[:location].present?
  listings
end
```

Comment: What specifically does "doesn't work" mean? What is in `params[:search]` when it doesn't work and what records to you expect it to find? BTW, you're installing PostgreSQL in your development environment as soon as you get this fixed, right?

Comment: The search does not return any results.  The search string should look for the word or phrase in :title, :description, and  :shortdescription.  But it returns no results.  It does not throw an error though.  

And I think I will take your advice and put PostgreSQL in my development after this.

Comment: I just figured out that it is working but is case sensitive in the search.  I can deal with that!

Comment: The case sensitivity of LIKE is database dependent, in PostgreSQL you'd use ILIKE to get a case insensitive version of LIKE. ActiveRecord doesn't give you much in the way of useful database portability. So yeah, get busy getting PostgreSQL going in your development environment :)

Answer (score 0):

This code does work - it is just case sensitive.